# How to set the default item in the drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I display the default value in the drop-down list using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/api/select/)? I tried to add `displayEmpty="true"`, but nothing changed.

I would like to have the first option `A` selected by default, so that a user can see it in UI. Currently, a user should click on the drop-down menu in order to select an item from the list. No item is selected by default (the selected item is blank by default).

```
const options = [
  {label:"A",value:483.93},
  {label:"B",value:8033.86},
  {label:"C",value:1246.3}
]

<Grid item xs={true}>
  <FormControl
      className={this.props.styles.formControl}
      margin="normal">
      <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="distanceTarget-label-placeholder">
          Target:
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("distanceTarget", event)}
        value={this.props.state.distanceTarget}
        input={<Input name="distanceTarget" id="distanceTarget-label-placeholder" />}
        displayEmpty="true"
        name="distanceTarget"
      >
      {options && options.length && options.map((option, i) => {
          return <MenuItem value={option.value} key={i}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
      })}
      </Select>
  </FormControl>
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is what I tried as suggested in comments, however I still have the same issue:

```
{options && options && options((option, i) => {
  if (i===0) {
    return <MenuItem value={option.value} key={i} selected={true}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
  }
  else {
    return <MenuItem value={option.value} key={i}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
  }
})}
```

Comment: set `selected = true` for the element you want to be selected by default

Comment: @CodeManiac: How can I do it inside `map`? something like `if i==0 then...`?

Comment: Yes, use `if...else` and return `MenuItem` with and without `selected` property as per your requirement, i.e   i == 0 ?  `<MenuItem selected={true}...` : `<MenuItem value={option.value} key={.......`

Comment: @CodeManiac: I tried this approach, but the default value does not appear. Please see my update for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Add displayEmpty not displayEmpty="true".

```
    <Select
    onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("distanceTarget", event)}
    value={this.props.state.distanceTarget}
    input={<Input name="distanceTarget" id="distanceTarget-label-placeholder" />}
    renderValue={value => ${value}`} // you should add your default value here
    name="distanceTarget"
```

Render the selected value. You can only use it when the native prop is false (default). (material-ui docs)

Comment: In my case the value is different from displayed label. I want to display `A`, while the corresponding value is `483.93`. If I use your approach, then I will see `483.93` instead of `A`. Or did I miss something? 
Is there any way to just specify `selected={true}`? Surprisingly it does not work for me.

Comment: I really don't know, but it should work. After you <select> you add default placeholder menu item

        <MenuItem value="" disabled>
            A
          </MenuItem>
{options && options.length && options.map((option, i) => {
          return <MenuItem value={option.value} key={i}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
      })}
      </Select>

Comment: Your code that you posted in the answer works, but the thing is that it displays the value, e.g. 483.93, but not the label, e.g. "A". If I write `renderValue={value => "A"}`, then apparently I will get wrong non-numeric value.
Regarding `displayEmpty`, I dropped `={true}`, but it did not have any effect.

Comment: So 'A' seems like a placeholder right? In material UI there is an example of the component with placehder. It calls placeholder. Check it. In docs. The total it seems like <Select *your atributes*>  <MenuItem value="" disabled> A </MenuItem>  {options && options.length && options.map((option, i) => { return <MenuItem value={option.value} key={i}>{option.label}</MenuItem> })} </Select> So try this one

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a particular item selected by default, you should initialize the state that control's the `Select`'s value to have that item's value. For instance, in my modified version of your code, I am initializing the `Select`'s value to `options[0].value`.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  FormControl,
  Input,
  InputLabel,
  Select,
  MenuItem
} from "@material-ui/core";
const options = [
  { label: "A", value: 483.93 },
  { label: "B", value: 8033.86 },
  { label: "C", value: 1246.3 }
];

function App() {
  const [distanceTarget, setDistanceTarget] = React.useState(options[0].value);
  return (
    <FormControl margin="normal">
      <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="distanceTarget-label-placeholder">
        Target:
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        onChange={event => setDistanceTarget(event.target.value)}
        value={distanceTarget}
        input={
          <Input name="distanceTarget" id="distanceTarget-label-placeholder" />
        }
        name="distanceTarget"
      >
        {options &&
          options.length &&
          options.map((option, i) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem value={option.value} key={i}>
                {option.label}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Default select value]